# Set Gravity for Toolbar (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, android-toolbar

i need to set Gravity programmatically to Bottom. It's loks like the default value is Top.The attributes in the Comment specifically for the Toolbar on this Fragment. My Idea is to add the chances on onCreateView and remove onDetach.

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(toolbar.getLayoutParams());
 params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(toolbar.getLayoutParams());
 newParams.height = dpToPx(128);
 //need to set gravity
 toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, dpToPx(28));

 toolbar.setLayoutParams(newParams);

 /*android:layout_height="128dp"
   android:gravity="bottom""
   android:paddingBottom="28dp"*/
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not do this in XML?

Comment: Because it's specifically for the Toolbar on this Fragment. Only on one fragment I extended the toolbar and append a floating button.

Comment: You can use XML. What do you mean your "extended" the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

To move one of the toolbar controls to the bottom of the toolbar, don't set the layout parameters on the toolbar itself. You need to set the gravity of the view  you are trying to move:

```
control.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Sorry don't work, it's put the complete Toolbar to the bottom. I will only put the Titel text to the bottom of the toolbar.

Comment: That's what I thought you were trying to do. I just updated my answer.

Comment: How can i get the Title View or control ?

Comment: Honestly you didnt even mention getting the title textview in your question. It's a completely different question now, I dont know the answer to that one

Comment: Sorry :( i forget ist in the main questions, but i mentioned in the comment 4 houres ago. Maybee Scrrenshot make it plainer.

Comment: What you should do is start a new question and ask exactly what you need. Mentioning it in the comments you will never get an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

First with `android:gravity="bottom"`

[image]

[image]

Comment: New Account can not post all Screenshots, must wait 3 Minutes.